# templated addable class with variadic pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

Good day,

I tried to implement a class which could summary everything with an inner stored variable `_val`, see below:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class Addable {
    T _val;

  public:
    explicit Addable(T v) :_val(std::move(v)) {}

    template <typename ...Us>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T add(Us&& ...us) const
    {
        return (_val + ... + us);
    }

    template<typename U>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T add(U u) const
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<U>>) {
            auto copy = _val;
            for (auto& n : copy) {
                n += u;
            }
            return copy;
        }
        else {
            return _val + u;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    assert(Addable<int>{42}.add() == 42);
    assert(Addable<int>{42}.add(1) == 43);
    assert(Addable<int>{42}.add(1, 1) == 44);
    assert(Addable<int>{2}.add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) == 7);

    {
        vector v {2, 3};
        vector expected {3, 4};
        assert(Addable<vector<int>>{v}.add(1) == expected);
    }

    {
        vector v {2, 3};
        vector expected {5, 6};
//        assert(Addable<vector<int>>{v}.add(1, 2) == expected); // compile error...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Class works
- with a *fold expression* with a simple `T` like `int` here.
- with a `T` like a `std::vector` but only for one `U u`.

When I try to append for each vector element one of each from *variadic pack* its broke, what I did wrong?...

Comment: Working solution [here](https://godbolt.org/z/cfAIk1).

Answer (score 1):

This one overload handles all your test cases:

```
template <typename ...Us>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr T add(Us&& ...us) const
{
    if constexpr (!sizeof...(us))
    {
        return _val;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector< std::common_type_t<Us...> > > )
    {  // [2]
        auto copy = _val;
        for (int& i : copy)
            i += (us + ...);
        return copy;
    }
    else
    {
        return (_val + ... + us);
    }
}
```

In [2] block which is invoked for `T = vector` you need to iterate over all items in copy, and for each one you have to add a result of folding `(us + ...)` from input arguments.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T3AB0W)

Answer (score -1):

> When I try to append for each vector element one of each from variadic pack its broke, what I did wrong?..

I don't understand what do you exactly want... anyway

With

```
Addable<vector<int>>{v}.add(1, 2)
```

you call `add()` with **two** arguments.

You have two version of `add()`: the variadic one and the one that receive **one** argument.

So, calling it with **two** arguments, only the variadic matches

```
template <typename ...Us>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr T add(Us&& ...us) const
{
    return (_val + ... + us);
}
```

but the operator `+` in `_val + ... + us`, where `_val` is a `std::vector<int>` and the `us...` values are `int`s, is undefined. So the error.

If you call `add()` with a single argument, by example

```
Addable<vector<int>>{v}.add(2)
```

the code compile (calling the `add()` version that manages the `std::vector` case) but, obviously, the `assert()` fail when you run the compiled program.